# How to adjust Navbar height and add hover color to links?

Tags: html, css

When I try to adjust the height of my Navbar, the collapse button does not work properly (I've tried doing style="height: 60px;" and also something like .navbar {height: 60px;} but the collapse menu stops working). Also, the Navbar collapse button does not close the menu, it can only open it (it closes it, then glitches out and opens it back up). I also wanted to add a hover color to the "about" link and set an active color when in the section but couldn't figure it out. Thanks

When I try to adjust the height of my Navbar, the collapse button does not work properly (I've tried doing style="height: 60px;" and also something like .navbar {height: 60px;} but the collapse menu stops working). Also, the Navbar collapse button does not close the menu, it can only open it (it closes it, then glitches out and opens it back up). I also wanted to add a hover color to the "about" link and set an active color when in the section but couldn't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Is there any other CSS you have for the navbar?

Comment: No, there's nothing related to the Navbar in my CSS file

Comment: Are you using any framework or library for the navbar? It seems like that... and that it is the js code for the button that is interfering

Comment: The height is currently bigger than 60px, so that doesn't work. I was trying to make it smaller to 60px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more than likely have an issue with your integration of either Bootstrap, JQuery, or Popper.js (or all three).

When I copied your code and added:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in the `<head>` and then:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

as the **LAST** thing before the `</body>` tag, it worked. See this CodePen I set up:
https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/ZEbPgvK

As for the hover, since you declared a color on the element, you can change it like this:

```
.nav-link:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Both of these worked great. I think it was something wrong with the links I included. Could you explain why you wouldn't include all of the links in the head, and some need to be put in the body?

Comment: Also, I'm still having trouble adjusting the height to 60px, the collapse menu doesn't work properly when I click it after I try changing it to 60px

Comment: Are you trying to add the height to the entire nav or just a certain part of it?

Comment: I'm wanting to just shrink the navbar to 60px height, not the collapse menu or anything.

Comment: @pumpkinchugger Your best option might be to adjust the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to achieve that target height. By setting a fixed height, you might run into issues allowing the "dropdown" to expand properly on mobile, since you'd have a fixed height set.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly, really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @pumpkinchugger No problem, glad I could help. I use a lot of Bootstrap and have run into many problems, but it’s usually silly things that cause them. Just keep doing research and it’ll become a great resource going forward